# How can I embed a twitter timeline in a Durandal view?

Tags: durandal

The code to embed the widget is nice and simple, but it includes javascript in tags.

Durandal appears to strip out such script tags.

How do I use the embed code in a Durandal view?

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/XXX" data-widget-id="XXX">Tweets by @XXX</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a custom Knockout binding, or create a Durandal widget where the view is your  tag, and the viewModel handles the JavaScript in your  tag.

Some notes: In your widget's view model, you would avoid `d.getElementsByTagName(s)` in favor of simply referencing the view reference passed in to either the `attached` or `compositionComplete` handler that Durandal provides.  In fact, you could pretty much eschew all direct DOM manipulation in favor of Durandal's imported view references and Knockout's/Durandal's templating/composition.

**UPDATE**

Take a look at this from the documentation you reference: *"If you’re already including our ‘widgets.js’ JavaScript in your page to show embedded Tweets or Twitter buttons, you don’t need to include this script again; it updates automatically to support new features."*

This could lead you down the path of simply referencing **widgets.js** in a script tag *in your index.html or index.chtml file*.

**You cannot use script tags in Durandal views, but you can use them in your index page.**

**SECOND UPDATE**

Once **widget.js** has been referenced in a script tag in the index.html or index.chtml (or perhaps even by using AMD), it becomes a matter of choosing the proper *Durandal* point at which to load the Twitter widget.  This could be either in the `attached` handler or in the `compositionComplete` handler, as indicated above.

As the OP pointed out in his comments, a functional place to do this is `compositionComplete`, in the following manner:

```
var compositionComplete = function () {
    twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

as documented [here](http://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization).

This assumes that `twttr` is either on the window or injected into the viewModel.

**POSSIBLE MEMORY LEAK**

It is equally important to note that unloading of widgets must take place in the Durandal's `detached` handler.  Use Twitter's API to unload, and then be sure to nullify the windows reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The update was very useful and gave me a start point. I removed the script tag and manually referenced the widget.js. The second half was getting the widget script to run on command i.e. after the element is added to the DOM. Achieving this was simply calling a function in compositionComplete. function compositionComplete() { twttr.widgets.load(); }; as documented here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization If you'd like to update your answer with this second part, I'll gladly accept it as 'the' answer.

Comment: @AndyJ Glad I could be of help.  I have updated the post, as you requested, and I added a section covering a possible memory leak, including where to address the leak in the Durandal lifecycle.  Your next step will be to develop a custom Knockout binding, and then use the async plugin for RequireJS to asynchronously inject the widgets reference.  You may be able to get away with not having to carry it around on the window.  We did that with Google Maps.

Comment: Just came across this answer _after_ I'd solved it myself.  I also found compositionComplete was an ideal place to load the widget, after loading widget.js in my shell.